# Symlink not recognized under su command

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I've a script that runs on AWS EC2 instance when it starts

`su -c "program_to_run" ec2-user`

Now program_to_run in its turn calls to `python3 script.py` and the fails wit the message:
`/bin/sh: python3: command not found`

If I log directly as ec2-user everything is running as expected.

I noticed that python3 is just a symlink to python3.6 so my guess is that symlink is not loaded with the su command.

How can I fix this?

NOTE:
I cannot change the way the script is being called in the program_to_run, assume that this is a binary code I'm not in control of its content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the culprit is probably the `PATH` variable.

The `su` command has a `-l` option that "Starts the shell as login shell with an environment similar to a real login" (see `man su`).

So, using `su -l -c "program_to_run" ec2-user` will most likely do the trick, since it will initialize the PATH variable similar to a real login.

Comment: Hi, it was in fact related to the PATH. As I need also to run with -p, -l will not help. but I changed the PATH as part of the command.